# TurtleCoin fork: how to define addresses prefix for miner?

Tags: bitcoin, cryptocurrency, monero

I forked TurtleCoin and customized some config including addresses pefix. I compiled it on Windows using Visual Studio. `Wallet` and `daemon` work fine but `miner` do not work. When I start miner and add address get this message:

```
Address is not valid: The address does not have the correct prefix corresponding to this coin - it appears to be an address for another cryptocurrency.
```

Where can I define addresses pefix for `miner`?

I followed these steps: https://github.com/turtlecoin/turtlecoin#windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, looking over the codebase this error is referred to as `ADDRESS_WRONG_PREFIX`. Which is returned by an the function `validateAddresses` which the mining code calls, [here](https://github.com/turtlecoin/turtlecoin/blob/239aa35f493588dd8009da12b045bff2953555e7/src/Miner/MiningConfig.cpp#L92).

This function simply checks that the prefix matches `WalletConfig::addressPrefix`, meaning that as long as you changed the address prefix in the wallet config located [here](https://github.com/turtlecoin/turtlecoin/blob/development/src/config/WalletConfig.h#L13). It should work.. I hope this is helpful.